# Создать массив сведений

Tags: delphi, pascal

Дан массив, с данными об автомобилях (StringGrid1), мне нужно ввести в Edit название авто, если таковой имеется, вывести полную строку в StringGrid2.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a,b:array of TCar;
    f:boolean;
    i,j,n,m:integer;
begin
n:=spinedit1.value;
setlength(a,n);
for i := 0 to n-1 do
begin
  a[i+1].carbrand:=stringgrid1.cells[1,i+1];
  a[i+1].registr:=stringgrid1.cells[2,i+1];
  a[i+1].lastname:=stringgrid1.cells[3,i+1];
  a[i+1].date:=stringgrid1.cells[4,i+1];
end;
m:=0;
f:=false;
 repeat
  if (edit1.Text=stringgrid1.cells[1,m]) then f:=true else m:=m+1;
 until ((m>n) or f);
  { if f then
  showmessage('+') else showmessage('-'); }
for i := 0 to m-1 do
setlength(b,m);
  begin
    stringgrid2.Cells[1,i+1]:=b[i].carbrand;
    stringgrid2.Cells[2,i+1]:=b[i].registr;
    stringgrid2.Cells[3,i+1]:=b[i].lastname;
    stringgrid2.Cells[4,i+1]:=b[i].date;
  end;
end;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, не выводит подходящие строки в StringGrid2?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Не

```
for i := 0 to m-1 do
setlength(b,m);
  begin
    stringgrid2.Cells[1,i+1]:=b[i].carbrand;
    ...
```

a

```
setlength(b,m);
for i := 0 to m-1 do
begin
  stringgrid2.Cells[1,i+1]:=b[i].carbrand;
  ...
```

Я не понимаю смысла последнего цикла. Вы распределяете память для массива `b`, а потом сразу начинаете оттуда читать. Как в `b` должны попасть данные?

С первым циклом тоже далеко не все в порядке. Вы выделяте память в массиве `а` на `n` элементов. Индексация динамических массивов идет от `0` до `Length - 1`. Вы же в первом цикле обращаетесь к элементам `а` от 1 до `n`. У Вас в опциях проекта включен "Range Checking"?

Comment: спасибо, но мне приходиться 3 раза нажимать на bitbtn чтоб вывелась вся строка)

Comment: Range Checking не включен

Comment: @ArtyomBelyk Включите его, и никогда не выключайте.

Comment: новые ошибки подъехали)) буду разбираться

Comment: @ArtyomBelyk - Удачи!

Comment: спасибо, взаимно!